# How to draw thousands squares on GoogleMap using android api V2

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es, rendering, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to draw on a Map ( Google Map android api v2 ) a lot of squares( 1000 + ), and a few circle.

Under android api V1 it was possible to do that but with the new api it's hard to draw more of 400 squares ( after it's  too slow ).

So I don't know how to to for solve this problem.
It is possible to use one google map and a textureView ?
( for draw my squares in opengl )

Answer (score 1):

I've got a test file with 1000 polygons and 35000 lat/lng pairs total and am able to load that from a file to a Google Maps V2 map in about 4 seconds on a Nexus 10.  I also have a test file of 12000 polygons, 48000 lat/lng pairs, that loads in about 20 seconds.  But supporting datasets larger than that seems to be without a purpose as with this many objects the map is fairly slow to scroll around.  And the Nexus 10 is one of the fastest Android devices out there.

I give you these numbers to give you an idea of what performance you might be able to extract.  I would say Maps V2 in general is faster than I was able to do on Maps V1, although my skills are further developed, I have spent more time optimizing, and devices have gotten faster since I was using Maps V1.

Most of the optimizations that I have made actually involved things other than the map itself so you might not want to jump to the assumption that Maps is the problem.  For instance, I used to load the data from SQLite and didn't have proper indexes on the tables.  Fixing that gave ~50% speedup.  Then I changed my app to load directly from shape files instead of the database and that helped some (but mostly I avoid the slow process of importing to the database).

So in the end my advice to you is to bust out `System.getCurrentMillis()` (writing to LogCat) and see where the actual performance bottlenecks are.  1000 squares should have OK performance on Maps V2 although it is probably slow enough to warrant a loading progress indicator.